# Oracle Pattern Matching Regular Expression REGEXP_LIKE to POSTGRES Equivalent?

Tags: regex, postgresql

Any idea on what would be the right function in Postgres to convert  the Oracle Pattern Matching Regular Expression REGEXP_EXP ?
I'm converting the source code from Oracle to Postgres,

ORACLE

```
IF REGEXP_LIKE(j.TRK, '^[0-9]+$') THEN
```

For Postgres we are using the following code,

```
IF aws_oracle_ext.regexp_like(j.trk, '^[0-9]+$') THEN
```

I need something native to Postgres without Oracle Extensions.

Comment: Use the `~`  operator in Postgres

Comment: [POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Comment: `if j.trk ~ '^[0-9]+$' then...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql has an operator for that `~` .  This operator maps to the internal function `textregexeq()`, which you may also use explicitly if you want to keep your existing syntax.

The internal function is defined as:

```
boolean pg_catalog.textregexeq(text, text)
IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT
```