# String matching for string that should start with abc:skp: and after that only digit only

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to do string matching for string that should start with abc:skp: and after that only digit only.

This is what I am looking to implement on PostgreSQL.

For example string to check that to be true or false inside PL/pgSQL block

1. abc:skp:293043204 -- this valid and return true
2. abc:skp:23hj29490 -- this is invalid and return false

How can I do this inside a PL/pgSQL block i.e.

```
do $$
<<block_2740>>
---
end $$`
```

I have tried with the below things but not works for 2nd one

```
if TEXTREGEXEQ(item_pguid,'abc:skp:([0-9]+)') then 
-- checking
end if;
```

Comment: I don't see why you would need PL/pgSQL for this.  A simple SELECT that uses `~` will be enough. Also: there is no `TEXTREGEXEQ` function in Postgres

Comment: Try adding a `$` so it will only match numbers until the end of the string: `abc:skp:([0-9]+)$`

Comment: What function is this textregexeq?  It doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: this check i am doing for parameter value before it proceed to do update in different tables @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106205/oracle-pattern-matching-regular-expression-regexp-like-to-postgres-equivalent

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-matching.html

You could use the `~` text operator if you'd like, or use the `regexp_matches` function.
Below is an example of using regexp_matches. I also corrected your regex. You were missing the termination match of `$`

```
create or replace function sample_regex_match() returns void as $$

    declare
        sample_strings text[];
    BEGIN
    sample_strings:=array['abc:skp:293043204','abc:skp:456','abc:skp:789','dontmatch','abc:skp:23hj29490'];
    for i in 1..array_length(sample_strings,1) loop
        if cardinality(regexp_matches(sample_strings[i],'abc:skp:([\d]+)$'))>0 then
            raise notice 'The string "%" matches the regex', sample_strings[i];
        else
            raise notice 'The string "%" does not match the regex', sample_strings[i];
        end if;
    end loop;
END $$ language plpgsql;
select sample_regex_match();
```

This will output

```
The string "abc:skp:293043204" matches the regex
The string "abc:skp:456" matches the regex
The string "abc:skp:789" matches the regex
The string "dontmatch" does not match the regex
The string "abc:skp:23hj29490" does not match the regex
```